# Robust standard errors in R

Tags: r

I know of several ways to implement robust standard errors in R for OLS models, most of which stem from writing a function or using a few packages. Is there a way to implement these for ARIMA/VAR/AR models? Will the same procedure work?

Comment: This is strictly an R question.  Should migrate to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you.